# How to use the response of useMutation in react-query to display data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-query

I am using react-query's useMutation() to POST data, I am able to successfully post the data.
But, The response i am returning after successfully posting the data I want to use that response and display it in  component

For this I am using state, and i am setting state inside onSuccess function in useMutation() hook, but it is giving me error
**Error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'tidpWarnings' of undefined
at Object.onSuccess (UpdateMIDPPage.jsx:80)
at mutation.js:86**

Below is my code for reference

```
const UpdateMIDPPage = ({ open, handleClose }) => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  const [tidpFiles, setTidpFiles] = useState([])
  const [reportFile, setReportFile] = useState('')
  const [tidpWarnings, setTidpWarnings] = useState([])
  const [reportWarnings, setReportWarnings] = useState([])
  const [toggleVisibleIcon, setToggleVisibleIcon] = useState(true)

  const { mutate, data, isSuccess, isLoading, isIdle, isError } = useMutation(
    async (body) => {
      const resp = await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/midp/update', body)
      return resp.data
    },
    {
      onSuccess: async (data) => {    
        console.log(data)
        setTidpWarnings(data.warnings1.tidpWarnings)
        setReportWarnings(data.warnings1.reportWarnings)
      },
      onError: async (error) => {
        console.log(error)
      },
    },
  )
  const handleUpdateMIDP = () => {
    const body = {
      projectId,
      tidpFiles,
      reportFile,
    }
    mutate(body)
    // also tried this doesnt work eiter
    // mutate(body, {
    //   onSuccess: async () => {
    //     setTidpWarnings(data.warnings1.tidpWarnings)
    //     setReportWarnings(data.warnings1.reportWarnings)
    //   },
    // })
  }

  return (
    <div className={classes.container}>
      <div className={classes.action}>
        <div>       
          <Button
            onClick={handleUpdateMIDP}
            className={classes.updateBtn}
            variant='contained'
            disableElevation
            startIcon={<CheckIcon />}
            disabled={tidpFiles === [] ? true : reportFile === '' ? true : isSuccess ? true : false}
          >
            {isIdle
              ? 'Generate MIDP'
              : isLoading
              ? 'Processing...'
              : isSuccess
              ? 'Processed!'
              : isError
              ? 'Error'
              : null}
          </Button>
        </div>
        <div>         
          <Tooltip title='Toggle upload section'>
            <IconButton onClick={() => setToggleVisibleIcon(!toggleVisibleIcon)}>
              {toggleVisibleIcon ? <VisibilityIcon /> : <VisibilityOffIcon />}
            </IconButton>
          </Tooltip>
        </div>
      </div>
      {toggleVisibleIcon ? (
        <UploadSection
          reportFile={reportFile}
          setReportFile={setReportFile}
          tidpFiles={tidpFiles}
          setTidpFiles={setTidpFiles}
        />
      ) : null}
      {isLoading ? <div>loading ....</div> : null}
      {isSuccess ? <WarningSection tidpWarnings={tidpWarnings} reportWarnings={reportWarnings} /> : null}
    </div>
  )
}
```

If i comment the setState code inside the onSuccess, everything works fine.

Here is the APi response for reference

```
{status: "success", data: {…}}
data:
ignoreFiles: (2) ["test1.xlsx", "test5.xlsx"]
warnings1: {tidpWarnings: Array(3), reportWarnings: Array(0)}
__proto__: Object
status: "success"
__proto__: Object
```

Please help me in figuring this out, thx

Answer (score 4):

> For this I am using state, and i am setting state inside onSuccess function in useMutation() hook

The `data` returned from useMutation will contain the response returned from the api, so there shouldn't be the need to add extra state management